# when i pase database file in assets folder then Error is showing - Cannot create class-file

Tags: android

I want to use sqLite database in my application but i don't know how add database file in android app when i copy and paste database in assets folder database file doesn't paste an error dialog is showing that is "Cannot create class-file"

Comment: you pasting file in android studio?

Comment: yes android studio

Comment: you have to pass .db file in assets not your class file

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to getting what the problem is **but it works, if you paste file first on the desktop and then copy again that desktop file and paste it on android studio assets folder** instead of direct pasting to Android Studio.

Some reason the file paste not work in the Android Studio.